# Ajax requests with unobtrusive javascript over lists of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I really prefer using unobtrusive javascript to inline javascript. I find it much easier to work with.

The problem that I keep running into, is that I don't know how to get data for each specific element that I want to work with.

For example:

I have a list, and I generate the following HTML (this is pseudo-code here)

```
<%for e in list%>
    <a href="#" class="delete"><%=e%></a> <!-- <%= e.id %> ??-->
<%end%>
```

So I want to attach javascript to each of these <a> tags that will invoke an ajax post, but I need the "id" to delete the correct element from the back end.

```
$('a.delete').click(function() {
    // Ajax request using "e.id"
});
```

Some things that I have tried:

1. Building the href and using the `attr` method to send the ajax request to that url. (I don't really like this for POST requests, but it does work.
2. Using a `rel` attribute to store the data I need.
3. Using HTML5 `data` attributes. (I don't know about the availability of this in all browsers, and since we need to support IE6+ I don't really like the idea using this.)
4. Creating a form for each <a> tag and serializing that. (This seems like a lot of extra code, but it also seems really clean.)

What are the best practices for achieving this?

Comment: You can give them an id.  <a id="link_1">1</a>, <a id="link_2">2</a>, etc.

Comment: none of these were the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, and I found a solution to this that I am happy with. It may not be perfect, but this is the best alternative I have found so far.

To be fair, all of these answers are correct - they will work just fine. This is just a matter of aesthetics at this point, and YMMV.

So, in the same templating pseudocode:

```
<% for e in list %>
  <a href="#" class="delete"
     data-method="delete"
     data-url="<%= delete_url(e.id) %>"><%= e %></a>
<% end %>
```

And some jQuery that will do what I want:

```
$('a.delete').on('click', function(e) {
  var self = $(this);
  var method = self.data('method');
  var url = self.data('url');

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: method
  }).done(function() {
    alert('woot - success');
  });
});
```

I think `data` elements are currently the best way to know how to interact with the webservice. This allows us to use the same url helpers that we would be using in the view rendering.

Answer (score 3):

I often store this kind of data in the tag like so:

#### Attribute tag method

```
   <div id="list">
      <a href="/link" post_id="68">Some post</a>
   </div>
```

Then in jQuery do something like:

```
 $('#list').delegate('a.delete', 'click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault(); // Stop default click event
    
     // ajax stuff here
     // $(this).attr('post_id') = 68
 });
```

**Update:** The `.attr('post_id')` doesn't work in IE6.

---

### Alternative methods? Hmm....

All of these use the above delegate function.

#### In a dedicated element, using class, or id, to define the elements data:

```
   <div id="list">
    <a href="/link"><span class="hide post_id">66</span>Some post</a>
   </div>
```

- **Access by:**  `$('span.post_id', this).text()`

Probably one of the worser ideas for just simple ids, but if you need to store complex data then adding it inside an element could be an option.

---

#### In the href...

```
   <div id="list">
      <a href="/link/66">Some post</a>
   </div>
```

- **Access by:**  `$(this).attr('href').match(/\/([0-9]+)$/)[1]`

This method is obviously dependant on your url. This is one of the most unobtrusive methods, assuming your url structure isn't too complex or change often.

---

#### It's a ID. It's unique. Let's ID:

```
   <div id="list">
      <a href="/link" id="post_66">Some post</a>
   </div>
```

- **Access by:**  `$(this).attr('id').split('_')[1]`

Benefit to this method is you can also style elements based on specific IDs -- sometimes useful. It also makes the most sense. Your ID is unique. That anchor link relates to that post, that unique ID, so using the id attribute makes sense.

Comment: Nice solution but is it unobtrusive?

Comment: @pixelbobby: I suppose using `id="post-68"` would be less obtrusive. Or perhaps `data-id="68"` for [HTML5 and jQuery 1.5+](http://api.jquery.com/data#data2).

Comment: @mu is too short: yeah, I just re-read Wikipedia bit to ensure I was understanding the question  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

Use the `id` attribute to store a string w/ the id like so:

```
<%for e in list%>     
    <a id="link_<%= e.id %>" href="#" class="delete"><%=e%></a> 
<%end%>
```

And the read the id by splitting on something like an underscore:

```
$('#list a').click(function(){
    //old var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    var id = this.id.split('_')[1]; //thx @mu

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.someurl.com/delete.aspx?id=' + id,
        //...more
    })
});
```

Comment: You could also do `var id = this.id.split('_')[1];`, no need to create a jQuery object just to access its `id` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an ID to each `<a>` element like this `<a href=".." id="delete_<%e.id%>" >` then when you attach event to this link you can find ID via string indexOf and use related ajax function.